# Is there an API to get the legality of alcohol (or legal drinking age) by geo location?

Tags: geospatial, api, legal

I need to make sure alcohol isn't advertised to underage users or in countries / regions where alcohol is illegal.

Ideally using MaxMind geo codes but I'm sure I could map from any geo system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use a Github repo (fork your own) that other users can contribute to, which will help keep it up to date.

https://github.com/aihpos/drinkingage/blob/master/drinking.csv

Although for regulatory purposes, this may not be sufficient. Also, this is a really nuanced topic, so may be tough to capture with 100% coverage.

For example, Switzerland:

> 18 for spirits 16 or 18 for beer and wine depending on the Canton

---

Any csv can be turned into a json API, [although this example is a bit overkill](https://github.com/CodeForCuritiba/csv_api).